# adding class to element in function

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code which puts the tags from my word press post into my html

**HTML:**

```
<h3 class="tags">
    <?php 
            $posttags = get_the_tags();

            $tags = array();
            if ($posttags) {
               foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                  $tags[] = $tag->name;
               }
            }
            $newTags = implode($tags, ' / ');

            echo $newTags;
    ?> 
</h3>
```

I want to put a css class on the ' / ' that is put in between the tags

Comment: Try changing: `$newTags = implode($tags, ' / ');` to `$newTags = implode($tags, ' <span class="slash">/</span> ');`?

Comment: You should post as a answer @JonUleis